# Unable to view <my-project-id>.appspot.com on browser

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

Trying to understand how Google Cloud App Engine works, I am trying the tutorial mentioned in:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-with-google-app-engine-and-spring-boot-in-5-steps-2d0f8165c89

I can get the response "Hello Spring Boot!" on my local system using browser at "http://localhost:8080" but when I deploy the code to Google App Engine, I access .appspot.com then i fail to get the message "Hello Spring Boot!" but get 404 Error not found. I suspect this is an access/permissions issue but have not been able to solve it

Things I have checked:

1) My GCP has billing enabled for this project 
2) I can see that there is one instance for in App Engine dashboard
3) My Google application credentials in bash ENV variable points to the API key created for this @appspot.gserivceaccount.com
4) I have used GCP to deploy an earlier project for maven spring boot, this is a new project to test APP engine.

Comment: So, the deployment was successful? If so, Did you use the url given by "gcloud app browse"?

Comment: doesnt work. i am really not sure what the problem is/was. i have scrapped this example and worked with one provided by google itself

Comment: I just tested the example on medium that you shared and it all went fine. I don't think this is related to permissions since is not a 403 error. Have you checked the logs for the app? can you share if any errors on App Engine > Versions > Click on Diagnose for the specific version > Logs > On second filter dropdown select "All logs"